# What should i do to secure vsftpd along with Firewall in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server

I am using `vsftpd` and it is working good.
But I want to secure my vsftpd server.
Could anyone please help me how to do it ?.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use FTP. It's an old and dated protocol, which does not support encryption. It's inefficient, and in addition a lot of the server software is rather dated; from before security became a mainstream concern. In addition I'm willing to bet that Apache receives far more eyeballs. As does OpenSSH.

Comment: Okay.Could you please help me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Secure VSFTPD server with TLS/SSL encryption in Ubuntu 16.04:
https://www.ostechnix.com/secure-vsftpd-server-with-tlsssl-encryption/

How To Enable Secure VSFTPD On Ubuntu 14.04 With SSL/TLS:
https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/09/enable-secure-vsftpd-ubuntu-14-04-ssltls/

I just used the former to good results. The latter seems approximately the same. The answer is too involved for me to try to duplicate here.

Comment: Please don't just post links as an answer. Give a description of what the content is and explain how to accomplish the results.